# UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity throws exception when authenticated using AD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I have the following code to authenticate to AD:

```
PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(authenticationType, 
            Properties.Settings.Default.AD_NombreServidor, 
            $"OU={Properties.Settings.Default.AD_OrganizationUnit}, DC={Properties.Settings.Default.AD_Dominio}, DC={Properties.Settings.Default.AD_Sufijo}");

bool isAuthenticated = false;
UserPrincipal userPrincipal = null;

try
{
    isAuthenticated = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(userName, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate);

    if (isAuthenticated)
    {
        userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userName);
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    isAuthenticated = false;
    userPrincipal = null;
}
```

With this code, the `principalContext.ValidateCredentials` call returns true. I think meaning that the user and password correctly authenticates against AD.

However, `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity` call throws an error

> Username or password is incorrect

In this case, I saw that `principalContext` `UserName` property is null before `FindByIdentity` call.

Then I changed the code to this one (notice the `principalContext` instantiation):

```
PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(authenticationType, 
            Properties.Settings.Default.AD_NombreServidor, 
            $"OU={Properties.Settings.Default.AD_OrganizationUnit}, DC={Properties.Settings.Default.AD_Dominio}, DC={Properties.Settings.Default.AD_Sufijo}", ContextOptions.Negotiate, userName, password);

bool isAuthenticated = false;
UserPrincipal userPrincipal = null;

try
{
    isAuthenticated = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(userName, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate);

    if (isAuthenticated)
    {
        userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userName);
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    isAuthenticated = false;
    userPrincipal = null;
}
```

After `principalContext` instantiation, `UserName` property contains the username I am using and the call to `FindByIdentity` throws the exception:

> No such object in server

How can I do it?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Maybe `userName` is not the `UserPrincipalName`. Try calling `FindByIdentity` with `IdentityType.SamAccountName`

Comment: Finally it worked when I used this instantiation: `PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(authenticationType,            Properties.Settings.Default.AD_NombreServidor, $"CN={userName},OU=SERVICIO,OU=SOMEGROUP,OU=OTHER GROUP,DC=domain,DC=cl", ContextOptions.SimpleBind, userName, password);` keeping all the following code the same. I find that out by using `dsquery` utility. The question now is: how can I avoid using all those `OU` or is it mandatory to specify the whole AD path to the user being authenticated?

Comment: Try passing `null` for the `container` parameter. That may or may not work. Keep in mind that when using `SimpleBind`, [the documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.contextoptions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#fields) that "Communications may be sent over the Internet in clear text if the SecureSocketsLayer option is not specified with simple bind."

Comment: @GabrielLuci I have finally used `PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(authenticationType, AD_ServerName, $"DC={AD_DomainName}, DC={AD_Suffix}", ContextOptions.Negotiate, userName, password);`. Then I can continue with the process (calling `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity` and setting the claims). I am wondering why I should pass the username and password in the constructor. It does not work in other way. If I don't pass them, I can call `principalContext.ValidateCredentials`, which succeeds, but it fails when calling `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity`.

Comment: If you don't pass the credentials in the constructor, it uses whatever credentials your application is running with (which likely are not domain credentials). `ValidateCredentials` will use the credentials you give it in that method, but has no effect on any other use of your context.